How to find nested ListView items using Robot Framework?
I am writing a test script using Robot Framework to test on Windows Elements, usually on components like buttons in Pane or window. However, today I have encountered a button that is nested in a ListView and I could not send clicks as the element is 'not visible'. Any idea on how to have a Robot framework test that could send clicks to the list items in a ListView?
Tried defining the path (path:1|5|2) to locate the child item but it was not visible. It returns a 'ActionNotPossible' due to invisible component.

What is "Windows Elements" exactly? I'm unfamiliar with robotframework but do you know what techniques/APIs it uses to interact with desktop UIs? (e.g. UIA, MSAA, XAML-debugging?)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
